# Почему POST запрос возвращает ошибку 500?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

Есть роутер, и при попытке сделать на него POST запрос возвращается ошибка 500.

Я понимаю, что обрабатывается блок `catch`, но не понимаю почему. В чем моя ошибка?

```js
const { Router } = require('express');
const User = require('../models/User');
const config = require('config');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const router = Router();

const jsonParser = bodyParser.json();

const corsOptions = {
    origin: config.get('CORS.whiteList' ),
    optionsSuccessStatus: config.get('CORS.optionsSuccessStatus')
}

router.post('/login',
    cors(corsOptions),
    jsonParser,
    async(req, res) => {
        try {
            const email = req.body.email;
            console.log(email)
            const candidate = await User.findOne({ email: email });
            if (isEmpty(email)) {
                console.log(3)
                return res.status(400).json({
                    msg: 'Некоректные данные при регистрации'
                });
            }

            if (candidate) {
                return res.status(400).json({
                    msg: 'Такой email уже зарегестрирован'
                });
            }

            const user = new User({
                email
            });

            await user.create();

        } catch (err) {
            console.log(3)
            res.status(500).json({
                msg: 'Что-то пошло не так, попробуйте снова'
            });
        }

        function isEmpty(str) {
            return (!str || 0 === str.length);
        }
    }
);

module.exports = router;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**UPD**

Во время деббагинга я обнаружил, что проблема в этих строках:

```js
const user = new User({
    email
});

await user.create();
```

Здесь я создаю поле в mongoDB.

Почему-то `user.create is not a function`. С моделью все в порядке.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если всё норм с моделью, которая подключена так `const User = require('../models/User')` то правильно или `.save` от документа, или `.create` от модели.

1 вариант

```
const user = new User({
  email
});

await user.save();
```

2 вариант (возможно не точно, пишу по памяти)

```
await User.create({
  email
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Как я понимаю, никакой catch не срабатывает. А express ругается, что вместо процедуры ему суют промис.

Коллеги с зарубержного сообщества дали [хороший ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44813401/passing-in-async-functions-to-node-js-express-js-router). Я любезно его переведу для вас.

Существуют два решения в виде модулей: [express-promise-router](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-promise-router) и [express-asyncify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-asyncify)

**express-promise-router**

```
const router = require('express-promise-router')();

// Дальше использовать как обычный роутер с асинхронными функциями `async functions`.
```

**express-asyncify**

```
const asyncify = require('express-asyncify');

// Чтобы починить маршруты в объекте `app`
// замените `const app = express();` на
const app = asyncify(express());

// Чтобы починить маршруты в объекте `router`
// замените `const router = Router();` на
const router = asyncify(Router());
```

Вам нужно применить функцию `asyncify` только к тем объектам, для которых вы устанавливаете маршруты напрямую

https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-asyncify

Comment: catch исполняется, в вопрос приложил скриншот

Comment: @Voprositel ну если catch выполняется, то зачем тогда это бесполезное сообщение `'Что-то пошло не так, попробуйте снова'` вместо отображения `err.stack`?